# Google Analytics API does not return traffic per dimension (e.g. country/browser)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

When I query Google Analytics for traffic (ga:visits,ga:pageviews) filtered by ga:userDefinesValue with no dimension specified, within a time period (e.g. 2012-08-01 to 2012-09-01), I get a result:

```
Your query matched 1 results and the API only returned the following 1 results:

    ga:visits   ga:pageviews 
    7           21
```

The problem is that when I add any dimension to the query (e.g. ga:country or ga:pagePath) i get an empty results set:

```
(none) 
no results found
```

What could be the reason for this behavior?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you filtering by ga:userDefinedValue?

Comment: I am tracking a few sites and this is the destinction between them

Answer (score 0):

From your description you state you are using country and pagePath as a metric, this will fail as they are dimensions.

Add ga:country as a dimension and the report should work.